# Spooler-Less Printing on Linux

Tags: linux, printing

I'am trying to make my Canon Pixma MG3650 work
on my GNU/Linux (Debian derived)

Spooler-Less Printing is exactly what I am looking for
[openprinting guide for spooler-less printing](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/database/nospoolerdocumentation)
(There are advantages and disadvantages cited in the guide)

Installation steps

1. Installed driver from Canon [`dpkg -i cnijfilter2-5.20-1-deb.tar.gz`](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg3650.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit))
2. Ghostscript is present on my system (checked with `gs -h`)
3. Found `Canon_MG3600_series.ppd` trailing from CUPS install
4. Copied to `/etc/foomatic/direct/Canon_MG3600_series.ppd`
5. Added `*FoomaticRIPPostPipe: "| cat &gt; /dev/usb/lp0"` to `/etc/foomatic/direct/Canon_MG3600_series.ppd`
6. `apt-get install foomatic-filters`
7. `apt-get install a2ps`
8. `foomatic-rip -P Canon_MG3600_series -o docs /proc/cpuinfo`

on step 8 nothing is printed :( no message no error just hangs

Tested on (Windows and Linux with CUPS) so printer is OK

Am I missing something ?
Maybe you know other guide/tutorial for this ?

Comment: Do you mean "on step 8 nothing is printed"? Did you verify that `/dev/usb/lp0` is what your printer appears as?

Comment: yes its 8 step my bad ;) corrected and yes i've checked it

Answer (score 1):

> 7. apt-get install a2ps

This step installs [GNU Anything-to-PostScript converter](https://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/).<sup>1</sup> The command you mentioned would install it in a regular way, i.e. by downloading binary package from Debian APT repository and unpack on your machine.

So, **if this installation command failed or froze<sup>3</sup>, you can *safely* abort it** (press Ctrl+C) **and repeat this step** until it succeeds.

Though, *double-check your internet access* before repeating it.<sup>2</sup> Or, if you are installing from offline media, make sure that the correct installation disc is inserted, readable, and mounted in a correct place.

P.S. Also, as a basic assurance, in case that the installation command ended without telling a thing<sup>3</sup>, run this immediately after the command ended:<sup>4</sup>

```
echo $?
```

If it displays `0`, rest assured that the installation of GNU Anything-to-PostScript was actually succeeded; and you can proceed to step 8.

---

#### Footnotes

- <sup>1</sup> Used by `foomatic-rip` for converting plain text file to PostScript, required by step 8 as you are going to print the plain-text `/proc/cpuinfo` file.
- <sup>2</sup> Slow/intermittent internet connection is a very common reason why `apt-get install` gets nowhere; but you should at least see some status message while it was trying— see the next point.
- <sup>3</sup> `apt-get install` command *will* normally print at least *something*, even when it was baffling at a completely damaged system or non-functioning network. But in an unusual case that your system explicitly configured it to shush, use `-q0` parameter to override the shush configuration directive...

  ```
  apt-get install -q0 a2ps
  ```
- <sup>4</sup> It displays exit code of the previous command. On any Unix-like system, value `0` means success, and other values mean something went wrong.

Comment: I am sorry its my fault there was a typo not the 7th step but 8th was failing
( foomatic-rip -P Canon_MG3600_series -o docs /proc/cpuinfo ) command

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed a local `foomatic-rip` manual page, and found that the `&gt;` part is intentional because of limitations in PPD descriptor format— they are handled internally by `foomatic-rip` itself; so the [original OpenPrinting article](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/database/nospoolerdocumentation) was actually correct. Though, I still stress that the question in its original unquoted form was misleading (as it mistranslated the correct `&gt;` to an incorrect `>`).

Back to the issue, I'm going to ask you to **bypass some steps inside the raster image processor** to see if it avoided the problem:

1. Remove `/etc/foomatic/direct/Canon_MG3600_series.ppd` file.
2. Run `ls -lF /dev/usb/lp0` to check that the printer connection exists, and you have necessary permission to write to it.
3. Run `echo 'Hello Printer?' | foomatic-rip -P Canon_MG3600_series > /dev/usb/lp0`

If your printer produced a print with `Hello Printer?` text, congratulation! **Then you can follow these steps:**

1. Repeat step 3 and 4 from your question.
2. Open your `/etc/foomatic/direct/Canon_MG3600_series.ppd` in text editor, as root.
3. Repeat step 5 from your question (*as it currently reads*), but make sure that you inserted that line just *after* the `*PPD-Adobe: "4.3"` line.
4. Run `foomatic-rip -P Canon_MG3600_series /proc/cpuinfo`

   - Note that `-o docs` was omitted, see *Explanation* below for a reason.

**Note:** Just in case that the thing still froze; press Ctrl+Z, run `ps fT`, run `kill -9 %1`; then append the `ps fT` output, together with the first 10 lines of `/etc/foomatic/direct/Canon_MG3600_series.ppd` to the end of your question. (Don't forget to tab-indent them before appending)

#### Explanation

I also got trouble with my own `foomatic-rip` (4.0.17.256) installation when `-o docs` was specified too. For an inexplicable reason (i.e. bug), **specifying that option caused the raster processor to blow up** at the step where it tried to invoke `a2ps` — it did not quote the invocation command line properly...

When run with `-o docs`, it tried to run something like this in the shell:

```
a2ps -1 --medium=A4dj --center-title=Documentation for the PRINTER/ENGINE (recommended) -o -
```

- You would notice the lack of quote around `--center-title` option exposed parentheses to the shell, resulting in syntax error.

When the shell refused to run `a2ps`; **`foomatic-rip` would freeze for quite a while**; probably waiting for a result that never come. Give it a minute, and it would eventually terminate with exit code 9, without completing the print job.

If this got proven right, I might have to check out the latest Foomatic toolchain; and report this bug to the developer if the problem persists.

P.S. If that offending `-o docs` option was omitted, `foomatic-rip` would ask the shell to run something like this instead:

```
a2ps -1 --medium=A4dj --center-title=USERNAME@HOSTNAME -o -
```

- This command line has no quoting problem, so the conversion, rasterization, and printing would proceed normally.

Comment: Thank you it is an excellent remark but sadly after correction it still isn't working (same manner)

Comment: @Jean Molinier, I edited this answer to provide an alternate (completely different) explanation and instruction. Please test them again.

Comment: sorry for this huge delay and thanks for your effort.
I tested it and no it isnt working 
after all I opted for CUPS with deactivated daemon